# Why doesn't "COALESCE" work with "GROUP BY"?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `table` with this data:

```
+----------+------+----------+
| location | sold | scrapped |
+----------+------+----------+
| Paris    | 5    | NULL     |
| Paris    | NULL | 6        |
+----------+------+----------+
```

I want this:

```
+----------+------+----------+
| location | sold | scrapped |
+----------+------+----------+
| Paris    | 5    | 6        |
+----------+------+----------+
```

Why doesn't this query do that?

```
SELECT `location`,
       coalesce(`sold`)     AS `sold`,
       coalesce(`scrapped`) AS `scrapped`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `location`
```

Comment: It's because the `COALESCE` is not aggregation function. How you want to aggregate not NULL values, For example both rows have 5 and 6 in `sold` column?

Comment: Probably should look up what `GROUP BY` does.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `coalesce` is not aggregate function. You can see all aggregate functions in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html).

Probably you want to achieve this thing:

```
SELECT `location`,
       substring_index(group_concat(`sold` SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 1)     AS `sold`,
       substring_index(group_concat(`scrapped` SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 1) AS `scrapped`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `location`
```

Comment: This is the most rigorous answer. It can be shortcutted, as I did in my answer, if you know that there will only be one non-null value per column, but if not, use this.

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce` isn’t an aggregate function; it produces a value every time it’s executed, whereas aggregate functions produce a value for every group of rows.

However, you can get your desired result by using the aggregate function `sum()` instead:

```
select location,
   sum(sold) as sold,
   sum(scrapped) as scrapped
from mytable
group by location
```

Using `sum()` achieves what seems to be your general intention, but `max()` may also suit your need as it too produces your sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best way to get what I wanted was a simple GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT `location`,
       group_concat(`sold`)     AS `sold`,
       group_concat(`scrapped`) AS `scrapped`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `location`
```

This works to "telescope" all the rows together as long as the "blank" cells are `NULL` and not `''` or `0` (otherwise I'd have to search for and filter out commas, etc.). Works perfectly for my use case!

Comment: Result doesn't match your requested output.

Comment: Presumably, any of several aggregate functions will do.

Comment: It doesn't with more rows. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wvXFjj8ExSnXhhonxgKJN8/0 Check my solution. It returns only one value for each column.

Comment: I see what you mean. I should have specified that my use case is such that I'm guaranteed to only have one non-null value per column. My example was super simplified from the actual query I'm running.