# How to group MySQL rows by combining values that are not null?

Tags: mysql, null, grouping, coalesce

How can I merge/combine rows by selecting the **most recent** not-null value of each column in a grouped result?

| id | user | fruit | number | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | Apple | NULL | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | John | Watermelon | 32 | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | John | NULL | 72 | 2022-01-03 |
| 4 | John | Pear | NULL | 2022-01-04 |

The following does not work:

```
SELECT
  user,
  COALESCE(fruit) as fruit,
  COALESCE(number) as number,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I want the result to be:

```
Jane   Apple   Null
John   Pear    72
```

The problem is that COALESCE() does not work with value sets but lists only.

Many topics refer to MIN() or MAX() instead of COALESCE() as a solution. It will not solve this problem as I need the newer value to override the older. Not the lowest or highest value.

Answer (score 1):

As `COALESCE()` is not an aggregating function but works with a given list of values only, I found a workaround by @jsowa in this thread: [Why doesn't "COALESCE" work with "GROUP BY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360924/why-doesnt-coalesce-work-with-group-by)

Instead of `COALESCE()` we can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT())`.

Pay extra attention to the ORDER BY clause inside the GROUP_CONCAT().
The downside is that the separator must be a character **not used** in any of the values.

```
SELECT
  user,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(fruit ORDER BY created_at DESC SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 1) AS fruit,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(number ORDER BY created_at DESC SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 1) AS number,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user;
```

Returns

```
Jane   Apple   Null
John   Pear    72
```

Comment: (Moved) Very nice, and agreed much sleeker! I learned something new, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @SOS Thank you. Happy to hear that. :)